# Create spatial rectangle using two corners coordinates

Tags: mysql, spatial

I have two sets on latitude and longitude which represents upper right corner and bottom left corner of city area respectively. I need to create a square polygon to save it into Mysql geometry field and to be able to use GeoSpatial functions (such as ST_Within etc).

Example data

```
LINESTRING(39.593123999999996 51.013050500000006,39.460676 50.9353495)
```

My guess is to create a square from linestring (diagonal) but I can't find any proper function to achieve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have managed a solution. You just need to call Envelope function to get MBR square around linestring.

```
SELECT AsText(Envelope(GeomFromText('LINESTRING(39.593123999999996 51.013050500000006,39.460676 50.9353495)')));
```